# printf doesn't print variable float answer

Tags: floating-point, return, printf, cs50

trying to calculate the total of a bill after adding tax and a tip then splitting it between 2 people; the code compiles but doesn't print the end value.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);

int main(void)
{
    float bill_amount = get_float("Bill before tax and tip: ");
    float tax_percent = get_float("Sale Tax Percent: ");
    int tip_percent = get_int("Tip percent: ");

{

        float tax = tax_percent/100.0;

        float bill = bill_amount + tax;

        int tip =  tip_percent / 100;

        float total = tip + bill + tax;

        return total / 2;

}
        printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill_amount, tax_percent, tip_percent));
}
```

this is part of the cs50 course - on a side note I have been finding it very difficult as I run the code but usually it's incorrect and I can't see the solution until I've searched it up. Even then understanding it is still a feat in itself; like here why do I use return? I know it's needed because it was in loaded in for us but I don't understand it's use? In printf it uses half after the comma but how does it know what that value is supposed to be? I've tried doing:

```
float tax = tax_percent/100.0;

float bill = bill_amount + tax;

int tip =  tip_percent / 100;

float half = tip + bill + tax/2;
```

but this has errors when compiling because it doesn't like I declared half as a float I think. I'm not sure how much I'm supposed to understand but there is a lot of things cs50 makes assumptions I know when I've never done programming before; anyway any help is much appreciated - thank you

Comment: nwse, Curious, why use `float` and not `double` ?

Comment: we were asked to use float in this exercise

Comment: nwse, Why divide the tax by 2 instead of dividing the sum by 2?

Comment: that's my bad I think it needs to be in brackets I do want the whole sum to divide by 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a function *prototype* for `half` here `float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);` , but the function is never defined. When the program encounters the `return` statement it returns from the `main` function, and program is over.

Add the function definition and body after the closing `}` of the main function. This is demonstrated in `mario8.c` in the sample code, the discussion of which starts at 1:42:05 of the video.